# asp.net razor: items from list in model are not displayed in dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor

I am trying to display the items from my list inside my model in a dropdown.

I tried:

```
<select asp-for="Requeststatus" asp-items="@Model.ThemeLinkingType"></select>
```

This renders a dropdown list, but with an empty list.

However, if I try:

```
 @{
     foreach (var item in Model.ThemeLinkingType)
     {
         <p>@item.DisplayName</p>
     }

 }
```

I get my items from my list returned in a nice little (not dropdown) kinda list.

This is the getter:

```
public List<ThemeLinkingType> ThemeLinkingType
{
    get
    {
        var result = new List<ThemeLinkingType>();


        foreach(var item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(ItemType)))
        {
            var name = item.ToString();
            var id = (int)item;

            var itemToAdd = new ThemeLinkingType
            {

               InternalName = name,
               Id = id,
               DisplayName = GetDisplayName(name)
            };

            result.Add(itemToAdd);
        }

        return result; 
    }
}
```

SOmeone explain the issue to me please.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `asp-items` with a SelectList type data:

```
@{
    var l = new SelectList(Model.ThemeLinkingType, "Id","DisplayName");
}
<select asp-for="Requeststatus" asp-items="@l"></select>
```